# How to add an arbitrary RSS feed to Google Buzz

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes, google-buzz

I'm trying to use Yahoo Pipes to solve the feedback loop of Buzz -> Twitter (via FriendFeed) -> Buzz, but am stumped at finding a way to bring the Yahoo Pipe RSS output back into Buzz.  Does anyone know how to do this please?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this "feedback loop"?

Comment: So by default, Buzz will take in your feed from Twitter but not publish to Twitter.  I've been using FriendFeed for a long time, so what I've set up is that I take the RSS feed of my Buzz output into FriendFeed, which then publishes on to Twitter.  This means though that Buzz then picks up the Twitter entry and publishes that as well.  I can use Yahoo Pipes between Buzz and FriendFeed to stop that turning into an infinite loop, but the duplicates in Buzz are really annoying.  Ideally, I'd pipe a filtered subset of FriendFeed back into Buzz via RSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use the [Google Buzz API](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/) to implement this. It would be a simple app that pulls the Yahoo Pipe RSS and writes it to Buzz. You could implement it on the [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) and set up a [cron job](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) to run this task periodically.

Comment: Thanks - I was kind of hoping there was something less involved, but it gives me a good excuse to play with GAE.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a website with the Yahoo Pipes RSS output as the auto-discovery feed, set up bidirectional `rel="me"` links to your Google Profile, and then plug it in as a 'Connected Site' in Buzz.  I'm not sure this is that much simpler than the GAE + Buzz API approach since you have to create a site just for that feed, but it's another thing to consider at least.